# scroll function not working in google chrome

Tags: scroll

1)If i scroll the browser, if scrollTop() is greater than 50px then nav bar will come down.

2)It is working in Mozilla, but it is not working in Google Chrome.

3)In this i have inserted two libraries a)jquery-2.1.3.min.js b)bootstrap.min.js

4)below is the script what i wrote.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var scroll_top=$("html").scrollTop();
        if(scroll_top >= 50){
            $("nav.navbar-default").addClass(" navbar-scroll");
            }else{
                $("nav.navbar-default").removeClass(" navbar-scroll");}
        });
    });
```

5)Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vamsivelaga/waL67pkb/

Answer (score 0):

Use "body" or document instead of html.

```
    var scroll_top=$("body").scrollTop();
```

or document

```
    var scroll_top=$(document).scrollTop();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/waL67pkb/1/